# datetime convertion to date only php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

i'd like to convert this datetime that was generated by MySQL, i'd like to convert this to just Month and day.
This is my current format `2012-09-17 00:55:56`

and I want to convert it to `September 17` only

how can I do this using PHP code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do it directly in `MYSQL` using **[DATE_FORMAT()](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2012-09-17 00:55:56','%M %d')
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2272)

Answer (score 1):

```
date("F d",strtotime($datefromdatabase)); //with leading zero in date
```

or

```
date("F j",strtotime($datefromdatabase)); //without leading zero in date
```

Comment: 1.Do not use PHP for what MYSQL should do. 2. Do not use date() and strtotime() functions anymore, use DataTime class.

Comment: @glavić well I agree your 2nd Point. But I dont agree 1st one. Because we might need to manipulate same date in different format in same page, so in this scenario using MYSQL will just increase the length of the query and decrease the understandability of the query. If just one format is what needed then using mysql will be better. Moreover, using date function isnt that bad, it all depends what you are comfortable in, the function has not yet been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) solution:-

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', getDateSomeHow());
echo $date->format('F d');
```